# The GL_LINE_STIPPLE does not work in ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am learning OpenGL these days, and I tried to compile the example code on the book(OpenGL SuperBible)

The code likes this: first use `glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE)` to open the `GL_LINE_STIPPLE`, and then `glLineStipple(2, (GLushort)0x00ff)`, last I draw some lines, but when executed, it just displayed the normal lines.  (in Ubuntu)

However, I compiled the same code in windows, it worked!!

Why? Are there any different details between Windows and Linux?

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "GLWidget.h"
GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QGLWidget(parent)
{
    setFormat(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer));
}
GLWidget::~GLWidget()
{
}
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE);
}
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-100, 100, -100, 100, -1, +1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawLine();
}
void GLWidget::drawLine()
{
    GLint factor = 1;
    GLushort pattern = 0x00ff;
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    for(GLfloat i = -90.0f; i < 90.0f; i += 20.0f)
    {
        glLineStipple(factor, pattern);
        glLineWidth(5.0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2f(-80.0f, i);
            glVertex2f(+80.0f, i);
        glEnd();
        factor++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen from your comment answer to @Lefteris that you're using the Mesa3D/DRI based "radeon" driver. I suggest you download AMD's propritary driver (fglrx) fron their website, install that and try again.

Comment: Thanks for answering, as your idea, I had tried to install the latest driver, and the program runs perfectly, so the problem have been solved!!

Comment: But some other problems comes up, my notebook run not so fluently after I install a ati driver, for example, when I drag a window form, the window will Twinkle frequently,  I had taken long for solving this problem, but fail.

Comment: @user1149333: That flickering you experience is not a problem of your program, but an artifact how the driver internally manages window resizes. There's nothing you can do about it. It's not even a bug, because window contents after a resize, but before redraw are undefines and hence may be anything. I can confirm, that the very same thing happens on my machine. As for the Mesa driver: Not supporting line stipple for OpenGL-1.2 is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to tell us what OpenGL context you are using to see why it does not work. If in Linux it is an openGL 4 context for example glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE) is not a part of openGL 4.

On the other hand in Windows if you don't bother to create a specific openGL context you get the default which is a version that definitely supports glEnable(GL_LINE_STIPPLE).

So please tell us what OpenGL context you are using in Linux.

Comment: Manufacturers: X.Org
Shader flag: Gallium 0.4 on AMD REDWOOD
OpenGL version: 2.1 Mesa 7.11
gluVersion: 1.3

Comment: Hm if that's so then my answer is incorrect. According to openGL 2.1 reference page http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/  it was still supported back then.

I am afraid that we would need more information on the code as a whole to provide you with a more accurate answer in that case

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have add my main part of source, it bases on QT.

Answer (score 0):

Stippled primitives are TODO for [anything above a R200](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature).

Answer (score -1):

`glLineStipple` is a deprecated API so perhaps it was removed from the Linux driver.